# Pop THE RootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing an app that as first viewcontroller has an UIViewController.
This controller pushes a NavigationViewController that contains other controllers.
Now I need to pop the RootViewController of the NavigationController to go back to the initial UIViewController.
I tried with

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and the app crashes("Tread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address= ......)").
I tried with

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and nothing happens.

The initial UIViewController calls

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier" sender:self];
```

In the UIBuilder the segue is of type "Show(e.g. Push)"

Then I have a NavigationViewcontroller that contains the RootViewController and another Viewcontroller.
What I am trying to achieve is to go back to the first viewcontroller (the one outside the navigationcontroller) from the RootViewController. So I should have the navigationcontroller there.

What am I missing?

Comment: The reason nothing happens is that `self`, whoever that is, has no `navigationController`. You are talking to the wrong view controller. The problem here is that you need to unwind your entire "stack" of view controllers in good order; you will need more than one command, probably... Unfortunately your question does not describe your actual full set of view controllers so it is impossible to help any further.

Comment: I think you need to look at your view controller hierarchy. How does the UIViewController "push" the UINavigationController without a navigation controller of it's own? You'd be better off displaying the UINavigationController as a modal controller.

Comment: You might try, [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Can you tell me how you are pushing navigation controller? When trying something like this: [self.navigationController pushViewController:testNavigationController animated:NO] it will throw this exception "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported".

Comment: its only possible to push a view controller if your initial UIViewController is in a navigation controller. In that case you have pushed a navigation controller in view hierarchy of another navigation controller. So, you call self.navigationController.navigationController to get to the main navigation controller. Try using [self.navigationController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Comment: @TaimourTanveer nothing happens

Comment: I have recreated what i understood from your statement
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; works fine for me
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; also works

Comment: Can you tell me exactly which controllers your segue is connected to? If I connect view controller with navigation controller through push segue it will give me same exception I already mentioned - "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported". Screenshot of your storyboard would help me a lot to understand your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had a couple of GestureRecognizer still in place that were causing the crash of the app.
The right method was:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```